# API kitchen POSTing to drupal service

Tags: json, drupal, service, http-status-code-406

So I am using http://apikitchen.com/ to debug an issue I am having with a drupal service.

I use: http://vmstage.dop.com/mobile/user/login.json as the URL to test. Method is `POST` and add two parameters:

1. `username`
2. `password`

Set the `username` and `password` as whatever you like. It will return **`401 Unauthorized: Wrong username or password.`** which is what you should get since you don't know the `username` or `password`

I saw they had a mac osx version of this and when I run the exact same thing in their desktop program I get a **`406 - Not acceptable`**.

The reason I am testing in this is because an iPhone app I am working relies on the drupal services to login and I am getting the same thing running through the iPhone emulator.

Back to the API kitchen thing, it works through the browser, but not through their desktop program..makes me think it has something to do with content-type or port. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of APIKitchen. I don't think there are any differences between the web and desktop version but if you can provide a sample url with parameters I can quickly look into it.

Comment: Ah cool! Nice work on that, its pretty slick. Anyway, I figured out what the issue was. I was getting a 406 not acceptable because it saw me as logged in on the drupal machine. The error fails to mention that is the reason for the 406. So Once I called `http://vmstage.dop.com/mobile/user/logout.json` and then tried to login it worked

Answer (score 1):

Generally a 406 error is used to indicate that a request is malformed in some manner.  I am not familiar with the tools you are using, but I think you are on the right track in looking for things that might be different between the different requests.  You should look at the header differences (including content type).  Also, maybe there are some JSON encoding differences between the two different platforms that the API doesn't like.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately, I didn't develop the content on the drupal side and the person who did is on vacation for a week...greatttt